# SharePoint 2013 RSS View Web Part Not being crawled

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, enterprise-search, rss

In my search settings for the site I have selected to crawl web part content.

I run a crawl and other web part contents are searchable but the content in the RSS View Web part is not searchable.

Is there something else I need to configure for the content in the RSS to be searchable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried viewing the web page in question as the Crawl Account to see what content the RSS View is displaying?

Comment: Yes and it is viewable.